# Is there any difference between 'static transients' and 'transient Type aField' declaration for GORM?

Tags: grails, persistence, grails-orm, transient

Let us consider two Grails domain example classes.

**1st class:**

```
class Person {

    String name
    Integer counter = 0

    static transients = ['counter']
}
```

**2nd class:**

```
class Vehicle {

    String name
    transient Integer counter = 0
}
```

Will there be any difference in GORM persistence or domain class behaviour for the *Integer counter* field between classes *Person* and *Vehicle*?

EDIT: I know that *Person* class is the good way to do it as referenced by Grails docs. However I would prefer the *Vehicle* class way as it seems to be more obvious and easier not to overlook when reading a code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The two mechanisms define different kinds of "transience". `static transients` defines bean properties that should not be mapped to the database by Hibernate, whereas the `transient` keyword denotes a field that should not be saved by the Java object serialization mechanism (e.g. when using webflow). They both have their uses in different situations.

Comment: Yup, this is true. I was kind of aware about that, but when a property is put in static transients list, then it's not serialized either (for example when 'as XML' casting used). So it was behaviour similar to transient keyword.
I have also checked now, that transient Integer counter is exported to the DB schema anyway, so indeed those two have nothing common between.
Anyway, your answer is fair enough, thanks!